# Need Databsename in Oracle equivalant as sql server database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need to display database name of all the databases created on oracle server.
As done in SQL server we have queries like

> select * from sys.databases

I have Oracle Express as server. Using Oracle SQL Developer as client tool to connect to server and created database.
Connecting to server with different Name as: 
Connection Name : SampleConnection
UserName : username
Password:

How can I get "SampleConnection" name through query.

Comment: There is no directly comparable concept in Oracle that would match completely to a database in SQL Server. In most of the cases "databases" in SQL Server are mapped to schemas (=users) in Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

you want something like

```
SELECT * FROM dba_users where username='SampleConnection'
```

Comment: Thanks Moudiz for quick reply. In Connections treeview, we get list of connections that we create through New/Select Database connection window. How can I get this list. Your answer just gives username used to connect.

Comment: @Prashant  in oracle user = schema. the query should give you the list of connections you connect to the database

Comment: I'm newbie in Oracle, Pardon for any ignorance... dba_user gave username. Is it same as database name in oracle?

Comment: @Prashant yes it is the same check this [SO answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37012/difference-between-database-vs-user-vs-schema)

Comment: @Prashant: it's the same as the _schema_ name. There is no really comparable concept in Oracle that would map completely to a SQL Server database. Oracle's pluggable databases are similar but are still very different to SQL Server's database. In most of the cases SQL Server databases are mapped to Oracle schemas (=users)

Comment: After search over internet and the links provided, I came to conclusion that, there are various ways of fetching database name(schema name). Most people have stated that Username is same as Database(Schema) name but not vice a versa. hence decided to get schema name as database name which is acheived through "SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')  FROM DUAL". but yours is also correct and used widely. Thanks for the information.